# Where does the coffeescript underline method come from?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I've been digging around in the [atom/apm code](https://github.com/atom/apm/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=underline) looking the where the function definition, or package dependency is. It gets called in `src/view.coffee` on line 93

```
items.push(repository.underline)
items.push(pack.description.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')) if pack.description
```

But I'm not sure where that method comes from, or how I would be able to reproduce it in the node REPL. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repository.underline` is not a method (no parentheses), it's a property of the `repository` variable.

The [`repository` variable](https://github.com/atom/apm/blob/b7586287912dd3996a0aed9e1ab025a03d8c674d/src/view.coffee#L92) comes from [`pack.repository.url` or `pack.repository`](https://github.com/atom/apm/blob/b7586287912dd3996a0aed9e1ab025a03d8c674d/src/view.coffee#L52).

[`pack` is populated from a JSON HTTP API response](https://github.com/atom/apm/blob/b7586287912dd3996a0aed9e1ab025a03d8c674d/src/view.coffee#L59-L67). `repository` is in the `metadata` which comes from the JSON in `versions[version]`. `version` is decided by [`getLatestCompatibleVersion`](https://github.com/atom/apm/blob/b7586287912dd3996a0aed9e1ab025a03d8c674d/src/view.coffee#L33-L49).

Taking a [sample response for the minimap package](https://atom.io/api/packages/minimap) it appears all the `repository` values for specific versions are plain strings, so the `.underline` property doesn't come from an object there. As they are plain strings something has probably extended the javascript String prototype to include an `underline` property, but what?

From your [sample search](https://github.com/atom/apm/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=underline) it looks like `.underline` is used for terminal type output. Looking at the [`package.json` dependencies, the `colors` package works in that space](https://github.com/atom/apm/blob/b7586287912dd3996a0aed9e1ab025a03d8c674d/package.json#L27).

`colors` [adds a number of properties to the string prototype](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/blob/9f3ace44700b8e705cb15be4767845c311b3ae11/lib/extendStringPrototype.js#L20-L60), including [`underline`](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/blob/9f3ace44700b8e705cb15be4767845c311b3ae11/lib/styles.js#L35).

This is a good example of why extending prototypes can get confusing.